# DataContract object list to CSV String

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, csv

I have a list of Product(like **below**) object and I want to convert csv string from this object

```
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("title", Namespace = "")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("link", Namespace = "")]
    public string ProductUrl { get; set; }
}
```

**below** method is not give me the correct output

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "csv")]
public string GetCollectionAsCsv()
{
    if (WebOperationContext.Current != null)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/csv";
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"products.csv\"";
    }

    List<Product> resultList = _boutiqueManager.GetProducts();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Product obj in resultList)
    {

        sb.Append(String.Join(",", obj));
    }
    return sb.ToString();

}
```

**Result**
[image]

What I should I for here to get a correct csv result

Comment: You should define how you expect the "correct" csv to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Check this line you have:`sb.Append(String.Join(",", obj));`
you are appending the type of the object here, not some value.

Try something like `sb.Append(String.Join(",", obj.Name));`
for example to append the list of names

Comment: or alternately, override ToString() in your object to return all the desired properties in CSV